# IOS UILabel shadow generates weird upper shadow

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, shadow

I'm trying to apply a shadow to a UILabel, but I get an ugly upper shadow on the font.

As you can see the shadow is already far away from the font, but I'm getting this shadowed upper thingy... The font should be pure white.

Any idea? I could put another UILabel over it, but I think it's not the cleanest solution...

```
float width = 500.0f;
    UIShadowLabel *label = [[UIShadowLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5) - (width * 0.5), 150.0, width, 100.0) ];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    label.shadowColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xb1b0b0);
    label.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(15.0f, 15.0f);
    label.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(100.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    label.text = @"am";
```

[image]

Comment: Is this in the simulator?  The simulator doesn't draw as well as the phone does using Core Animation. Also if you post your UIShadowLabel we can look at the code.  It's possible that it's adding a stroke.

Comment: Nope, I can see this shadow on the device too.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code as per your need

```
[self.yourView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.yourView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[self.yourView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[self.yourView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```